# regex - как правильно убрать вложенные скобки?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, в которой встречаются такие вещи, как `(..(число)..)`. Скобок может быть от одной до много, но скобки расставлены правильно - например,

```
(((((4)))((5))))
```

Как правильно убрать скобки? Я сделал примерно так -

```
regex rx("\\((\\d*)\\)");
```

а потом многократно - пока срока меняется - замену:

```
string out = s;
while( (out = regex_replace(s,rx,"$1")) != s) s = out;
```

Но что-то мне думается, что вложенные скобки можно убирать одним заходом, просто я не придумал как.

Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: @user7860670 И как вы предлагаете им воспользоваться? Просто все скобки убрать можнго, а из `(a(4)b((c))d(5))`? Надо убирать только там, где встречается число в скобках.

Comment: Можно и в один проход, но будет нужен `boost::regex`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew А стандартным как-то можно?

Comment: У вас лучший вариант уже есть. А другого нет.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Вы о чем? О предложенном мне `remove_if`?

Comment: а можно пример строки  и  результат?  Не совсем понятна цель. Убрать только скобки вокруг чисел или парсить какие не нужны?...

Comment: `remove_if`  — это что-то из другой оперы. Я про ваш код. Именно такой подход и используется, если библиотека регулярных выражений не поддержтвает рекурсию или сбаланисрованные конструкции.

Comment: А `boost::regex`  "понимает" рекурсию, `\((?>[^()]+|\g<0>)*\)`. См. [пример](https://regex101.com/r/mDDJpR/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо! может, сделаете ответ, чтоб я принял?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Просто убрать согласованные скобки только вокруг чисел. Например, `(a(4)b((c))d(((5))))` -> `(a4b((c))d5)`

Comment: А, стоп, только с числами внутри? [`\((?=\(*(\d+)\))(?>[^()]+|\g<0>)*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/mDDJpR/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Да я принцип понял, нестрашно :) Все равно boost'ом пользоваться вряд ли буду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно такой подход, как в вашем вопросе, и используется, если библиотека регулярных выражений не поддержтвает рекурсию или сбаланисрованные конструкции. `std::regex` их также не поддерживает.

Если хотите, можете воспользоваться библиотекой `boost::regex`, которая поддерживает рекурсию:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "(((((4)))((5)))) ,,,,(((((4)))((5)))) 112 (((((4)))((5))))  (a(4)b((c))d(((5))))";
    boost::regex expr{R"(\((?=\(*(\d+)\))(?>\d+|(?R))*\))"};
    std::string fmt{R"(\1)"};
    std::cout << boost::regex_replace(s, expr, fmt) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
// => 4 ,,,,4 112 4  (a4b((c))d5)
```

См. [пример работы кода на С++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33f7fbbcd3902f9b).

[Регулярное выражение тут](https://regex101.com/r/mZiX16/2)

```cpp
\((?=\(*(\d+)\))(?>\d+|(?R))*\)
```

**Подробности**

- `\(` - символ `(`
- `(?=\(*(\d+)\))` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует наличия `(`, затем 1 и более цифр (захватываемых в подмаску №1), а затем `)` сразу после текущей позиции
- `(?>\d+|(?R))*` - 0 и более повторов 1+ цифр или же целого выражения (рекурсивно)
- `\)`  - символ `)`